# Can't Access Magento Admin from MacBook. Browser stuck in Development Mode

Tags: magento2.3

I am facing a really weird issue for accessing Magento Admin from my MacBook **for a particular domain only**. For a yet unknown reason, it is stuck at the time when was in development mode. Website is in production mode already. So, changes I make on Magento Admin on my MacBook don't reflect on store frontend. Other devices from home (other laptop or mobiles) are working fine and I can access with other admin credentials as expected. The problem is with my MacBook only (the main device I use for working).

I have tried everything: clearing all chrome history, deleted the apps, reinstalled, updated Mac OS. Excluded my account. Tried on Safari and Firefox. Incognito mode. Nothing works.

If I try logging with other credentials, return error: You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.

I have two websites on Magento... 1 works good, other one, I am experiencing the above commented.

Anyone has faced this issue before?

Magento 2.35-p2
Php 7.3

Comment: Have you tried on any other "Mac Book" devices?

Comment: I have two websites on Magento for different stores. Just noticed that my other website/domain is working good. Only one website/domain I can't access Magento admin

Comment: such things happened with me when I had host entries on my system for development server, and changes made on production server doesn't reflect to that particular machine, just a guess that this may be the case for you too

Comment: Many thanks! Seems that you are getting to the point. For some reason, although in production mode, it is stuck in development mode on my MacBook. I will update the question